# Filter a dataframe meeting some criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df:

```
df = {'Modality': {('002_S_0413', '1', '6/21/2017', 'DTI'): 1,
  ('002_S_0413', '1', '6/21/2017', 'FLAIR'): 1,
  ('002_S_0413', '1', '6/21/2017', 'T1'): 1,
  ('002_S_0413', '3', '8/27/2019', 'DTI'): 1,
  ('002_S_0413', '3', '8/27/2019', 'FLAIR'): 1,
  ('002_S_0413', '3', '8/27/2019', 'T1'): 1,
  ('002_S_1261', '1', '3/15/2017', 'DTI'): 1,
  ('002_S_1261', '1', '3/15/2017', 'FLAIR'): 1,
  ('002_S_1261', '1', '3/15/2017', 'T1'): 1,
  ('002_S_1261', '2', '4/24/2018', 'DTI'): 1,
  ('002_S_1261', '2', '4/24/2018', 'FLAIR'): 1,
  ('002_S_1261', '2', '4/24/2018', 'T1'): 1,
  ('002_S_1261', '3', '5/01/2019', 'DTI'): 1,
  ('002_S_1261', '3', '5/01/2019', 'FLAIR'): 1,
  ('002_S_1261', '3', '5/01/2019', 'T1'): 1,
  ('002_S_1280', '1', '3/13/2017', 'DTI'): 1,
  ('002_S_1280', '1', '3/13/2017', 'FLAIR'): 1,
  ('002_S_1280', '3', '3/06/2019', 'DTI'): 1,
  ('002_S_4213', '1', '8/14/2017', 'FLAIR'): 1,
  ('002_S_4213', '1', '8/14/2017', 'T1'): 1},
 'Phase': {('002_S_0413', '1', '6/21/2017', 'DTI'): 1,
  ('002_S_0413', '1', '6/21/2017', 'FLAIR'): 1,
  ('002_S_0413', '1', '6/21/2017', 'T1'): 1,
  ('002_S_0413', '3', '8/27/2019', 'DTI'): 1,
  ('002_S_0413', '3', '8/27/2019', 'FLAIR'): 1,
  ('002_S_0413', '3', '8/27/2019', 'T1'): 1,
  ('002_S_1261', '1', '3/15/2017', 'DTI'): 1,
  ('002_S_1261', '1', '3/15/2017', 'FLAIR'): 1,
  ('002_S_1261', '1', '3/15/2017', 'T1'): 1,
  ('002_S_1261', '2', '4/24/2018', 'DTI'): 1,
  ('002_S_1261', '2', '4/24/2018', 'FLAIR'): 1,
  ('002_S_1261', '2', '4/24/2018', 'T1'): 1,
  ('002_S_1261', '3', '5/01/2019', 'DTI'): 1,
  ('002_S_1261', '3', '5/01/2019', 'FLAIR'): 1,
  ('002_S_1261', '3', '5/01/2019', 'T1'): 1,
  ('002_S_1280', '1', '3/13/2017', 'DTI'): 1,
  ('002_S_1280', '1', '3/13/2017', 'FLAIR'): 1,
  ('002_S_1280', '3', '3/06/2019', 'DTI'): 1,
  ('002_S_4213', '1', '8/14/2017', 'FLAIR'): 1,
  ('002_S_4213', '1', '8/14/2017', 'T1'): 1}}
```

Sorry that I can't make the headers appear but they are as in this image:

[image]

I'm stuck in this step and I'll really appreciate your help!

I need a code that for each subject ID looks at the Description column, if DTI, T1 and FLAIR are present in a single Visit take that visit and delete the rest, if they are present in multiple Visits take the Visit with the minimum value and delete the rest. If DTI, T1 and FLAIR are not present in a single visit delete also those rows.
What I need is for each Subject ID get the minimum Visit value that has the three values in Description (DTI, T1 and FLAIR) and delete the rest

My output would look something like this:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: What is your expected output for this sample data?

Comment: Something like the table I just put, but knowing that not all the Visit have to be 1, that's the output in this example but in my data It has to be the minimun value that meet the rest of the criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that testing that 'Description' is exactly the 3 values 'DTI', 'FLAIR', 'T1' is required and just checking that there are `n` values in a given group is insufficient:

```
# Remove Description and Visit from MultiIndex
new_df = df.reset_index(['Visit', 'Description'])
# Create Set of Values to Check against
check_values = {'DTI', 'FLAIR', 'T1'}
# Create Boolean Index
m = (
        new_df.groupby(level=[0, 1])['Description'].transform(
            lambda g: set(g) == check_values and len(g) == len(check_values)
        )
        & new_df.groupby(level=0)['Visit'].transform('min').eq(new_df['Visit'])
)

# Filter Dataframe with Index and Fix MultiIndex
new_df = new_df[m].set_index(['Visit', 'Description'], append=True)
```

---

The two aspects of the mask:

1. Checks that the unique values from each group matches the expected and the length of each group matches the expected length

```
set(g) == check_values and len(g) == len(check_values)
```

2. Checks if this 'Visit' is the minimum value for each 'Subject ID':

```
new_df.groupby(level=0)['Visit'].transform('min').eq(new_df['Visit'])
```

---

Output (`new_df`):

```
                                         Modality  Phase
Subject ID Study Date Visit Description                 
002_S_0413 6/21/2017  1     DTI                 1      1
                            FLAIR               1      1
                            T1                  1      1
002_S_1261 3/15/2017  1     DTI                 1      1
                            FLAIR               1      1
                            T1                  1      1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm getting an error here: set(g) == check_values and len(g) == len(check_values) beccause g is not defined, what's is g in this case?

Comment: The middle two code blocks are explanation for how the mask works. Use it in the lambda as it is in the complete working example at the top.

Comment: Hey @Henry Ecker, could you help me with another question? Following your answer, if 'Description' doesn't have exactly the 3 values 'DTI', 'FLAIR', 'T1' but instead some of them are repeated (ex: 'DTI', 'FLAIR', 'T1', 'T1', 'FLAIR'); instead of deleting the whole subject I want it to check if the value is repeated and delete one of the repetead values  to fit the criteria, I mean to make it 'DTI', 'FLAIR', 'T1'. Dou you have any suggestion?

Comment: We don’t have enough room in the comments to discuss the details of this new question and fill out the answer. Additionally this is beyond the scope of this question. I recommend you create a new question with sample data expected input and output so you have enough room to fully explain the situation and can benefit from everyone’s input. =)